# Get a for loop in Uno to reverse order

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm attempting to make a Java version of the card game Uno. In the game there is a card that reverses the order of play so if Player 1 plays the card, Player 3 is next, then Player 2 and so on. However, I am having difficulty on trying to get:

```java
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    if(game.skipNext){
        game.playTurn((i + 1) % 3);
        game.skipNext = false;
    } else {
        game.playTurn(i);
    }
```

to reverse the order so Player 3 follows Player 1 etc.

I have this current code:

```java
while(game.gameIsActive){
    if(game.gameIsClockwise){
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            if(game.skipNext){
                game.playTurn((i + 1) % 3);
                game.skipNext = false;
            } else {
                game.playTurn(i);
            }
        }
    } else {
        int loopStart = (game.newlyClockwise) ? game.activePlayer - 1/* Starts with previous player*/ : 2;
        for(int i = loopStart; i > -1;i--) {
            if(game.skipNext){
                game.playTurn((i + 1) % 3);
                game.skipNext = false;
            } else {
                game.playTurn(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

as my game loop but it does not work. If Player 1 plays reverse, Player 2 still goes next.

Comment: it is unclear what you want or are asking

Comment: if user 1 plays then 3, 2
if user 2 plays then 1, 3
if user 3 plays then 2, 1
Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want to use a `for` loop to implement this logic. You want to reverse direction as soon as the reverse card is played, not at the end of the for-loop.

I would handle it turn by turn, treating the current player as part of the state, rather than a loop variable.

Try implementing something like this (pseudocode):

```
subroutine nextPlayer:
    if direction == 1:
        player = (player + 1) % playerCount
    else:
        player = (player - 1) % playerCount    

main loop:
    while game not over:
        play turn (player)
        if played skip:
            nextPlayer
            nextPlayer
        else if played reverse:
            direction = direction * -1
            nextPlayer
        else                 
            nextPlayer
        end if
    end while
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that looks like it will work :). I was used to using for loops but that would make much more sense